# ¿Cómo me aseguro de no ser redirigido a otra página sobre Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Estoy probando para saber si se pueden comprar algunos Tickers en EToro, es decir que hay una página en Etoro en formato `https://www.etoro.com/markets/ticker` y no una redirección por ejemplo para los siguientes tickers:

```
9       DD
18    ADBE
24     AGN
31    ATVI
47     AEM
```

AGN y AEM no se pueden comprar, no hay páginas sobre EToro y soy redirigido a https://www.etoro.com/watchlists

Por consiguiente intenté:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Programs\chromedriver.exe")
tradable = []
for ticker in df_red['Ticker']:
    print(ticker)
    location = "https://www.etoro.com/markets/" + ticker.lower()
    driver.get(location)
    time.sleep(2)
    current_url = driver.current_url
    if current_url == location:
        tradable.append(ticker)
```

Sé que no es óptimo porque podría detectar en caso de un cambio de url por ejemplo.

También quiero desplegar esto en la nube de Google, así que no estoy seguro de tener acceso a Selenium.